# Compile less files and minify js files in node.js project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, gruntjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the Eb Command Line Interface to deploy a node.js project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am using git for version control. So the command I run to deploy is simply 'git aws.push'.
Locally, I am using grunt to compile css files from less files and also minify and cmobine js files.

I don't want to include the *.min.css files or *.min.js files in my git repository but would rather have them recompiled on AWS after deployment. 
Is there a way to do this? Maybe with a .ebextensions hook or something?

Comment: Did some research on that. It looks like one way to do that is to modify the default Node command: in the eb configuration to 'npm start' and then add a prestart script in package.json to run a e.g. a grunt build task

Comment: If it works, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with grunt, but I guess what you would have to do is install nodejs and grunt on elastic beanstalk and then running your grunt commands once the container is set up.

In a ebextensions hook such as `.ebextensions/grunt.config` you could do the following :

```
commands:
  01-install-nodejs-npm:
    command: "yum install -y --enablerepo=epel nodejs npm"
  02-install-grunt:
    command: "npm install -g grunt-cli"

container_commands:
  01-compilecss-minifyjs:
    command: "grunt build mytask"
    leader_only: true
```

The commands would make sure nodejs, npm and grunt are installed. The container_commands are executed from within your repository's home directory, so the "source" files for your grunt build should be available from there.

Again - I don't work with grunt and can't tell if this would actually work, but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Returns error in log "Error occurred during build: 02-install-grunt does not specify the 'command' attribute, which is required ."

Comment: You are right, Thanks! I forgot to add the `command:` part in 02-install-grunt. Just updated the code. As said in the answer, this is untested code and is more thought as a starting point... I hope it works now.