# Excluding development code in production using elastic bean stalk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

have a node app running in elastic bean stalk which uses grunt to minify, ... I'd like to use EBS to push my code to an instance, but for the client side javascript, I only want to push the minified javascript and not all the client side javascript that is checked into git.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there were a couple answers here: [Compile less files and minify js files in node.js project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246882/compile-less-files-and-minify-js-files-in-node-js-project-on-aws-elastic-beansta) .

One involving writing a start script to do minify, the other using commands in the ebextensions files to install and run grunt before deployment. See also: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html .

Do those help you?

Comment: Not exactly, since the first and second links still seem to involve pushing all the files (minified and non-minified) to AWS. Maybe I should change my question - is it not a big deal to push all the files, minified and non-minified, to production? It seems a bit clunky to me.